# How can I find the fastest path by car to reach a US state from a given US location?

Tags: usa, driving, maps

How can I find the fastest path by car to reach a US state from a given US location? I.e., I'm located at address x and I want to know the minimum driving time to reach US state y.

Comment: I am curious, why a whole state and any place within that state?

Comment: @Willeke Different state, different laws.

Comment: Why not use Apple or Google Maps to show routes and times between x and the border of state y?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica AFAIK Gmaps requires users to indicate a specific address for the destination. idk about Apple.

Comment: Nope. Drill down until the map display shows the actual border, then right-click to place a "Directions to this Location" pin at that location. You'll easily be able to get the destination within meters of the border.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Good point, sorry I meant one has to specify a precise, narrow location: we can't ask GMaps for a shortest path to a large area (e.g., a 600km long border).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't know how you expect any website to compute directions to every possible location along a border. You can't do it for a neighborhood, much less a city, much less a county, much less a state whose borders might be hundreds and hundreds of miles long.

Comment: @choster same way as kiwi can do for flights.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt A country has at best a few dozen commercial airports. There are an infinite number of geographic coordinates along a border.

Comment: @choster Iet's assume I'm driving on a road.

Comment: If you restrict the problem to interstates only, it might be possible but there are usually lots of roads that cross US state borders. Routing problems are notoriously difficult to solve.

Comment: @mkennedy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths

Comment: There are some obvious common-sense heuristics, of course... since travel is usually fastest via major highways, identify the (relatively small number of) major highways that enter the state from the general direction of your starting point, find the point where each one crosses the state line, compute travel times to those points, and take the minimum.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes the problem can easily be approximately if needs be. Not to mention using the travel time history of people doing similar trips.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Ah yes, I was thinking of the traveling salesman problem which this isn't. That's NP-complete. The algorithm would still have identify most if not all segments/edges that cross the target state border and then calculate routes from origin to all targets. You could try to reduce by only check the closest sides but I could see a case where there might be no interstate-based route on the closest side. Hmmm.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: "fastest" also depends a lot on time of day depending on which road cloggs up at what time. I had two different routings from home to college: They would fork directly in front of my door and cross statelines at completely different points. The faster one was always determined by current traffic conditions.

Comment: @Hilmar yes GMaps and a few others take into account the traffic conditions.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open google maps
2. Get directions by car from your starting point to somewhere (anywhere) in your target state
3. **Slowly drag the destination marker around** along the state borders and watch the duration shown in the tooltip
4. Use your mind to keep track of when the duration is lowest
5. You have found your answer

Answer (score 4):

This has been something that I have often wished existed (although for me it's usually at the US county level). I don't have a perfect solution, but I do have one that in practice works *fairly* well. In other words, if your goal is a systematic solution *a la* a mathematical proof, this isn't the answer you're looking for. On the other hand, if you just want a functional answer, I think this one's usually good enough.

Let's say that you're in Mason City, IA, and you want to get to Illinois (I chose one that's kind of diagonal to make it interesting).

- By eye draw a line from Mason city to the IL border
- Look around and find 3-5 cities across the border near that location on the map. I chose Rockford, Sterling, and Moline. (first image)
- Use google maps to find directions to each of those locations. Note the border crossing in each case. (second image)
- Find directions from the starting point to the border crossing in each case. The times to the border for me were: Rockford: 2:47, Sterling: 3:31, Moline: 3:28. The route to Rockford wins.
- Now we have a pretty good idea that the US-20 bridge on the Mississippi river in Dubuque is probably the fastest way to the border. That said, one could continue to iterate by choosing more cities this time all very close to Dubuque. (You generally only have to do this in the eastern US where roads are laid out less systematically.
  [image: Image 1]
  [image: Image 2]

Comment: One thing that makes your example less interesting, actually, is that there is one point in Illinois that is significantly closer to your origin than any other point in Illinois.  This minimizes the number of potential alternate routes.  The quickest route from Maquoketa to Illinois is a much more interesting problem, at least at first glance.  Do you go via Dubuque?  Davenport?  Clinton?  Bellvue?

Comment: @phoog very true -- I was mostly just going for a proof of concept. And of course things like the Kansas Cities, where things get exceptionally complex!

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't think about that at all.  But I should have: I live in New York City, where for some neighborhoods the quickest route to New Jersey or Connecticut will be different at different times of day.